# Read a post parameter sent through axios in golang

Tags: javascript, go, post, axios, request

I am new to golang and try to understand this. I facing the following problem.

I am sending `axios` post as below

```js
const options = {
  data: {
    test: this.state.value,
  },
  method: 'POST',
  url: `/test`,
};
console.log(options)
axios.request(options).then(
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.value);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  },
);
```

And now in the Go part, I am trying to read it. But I am not getting how to read it in Go. I am tried with the following code, but it is not working. It is printing only `test Value`. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```golang
func routetest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    test, _ := param.String(r, "test")
    fmt.Printf("test Value")
    fmt.Printf(test)
    fmt.Printf("test Value")
}
```

Updated Code

```golang
func routeTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type requestBody struct {
        test string `json:"test"`
    }
    body := requestBody{}
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&body); err != nil {
        // some error handling
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    test := body.test
    fmt.Printf(test)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to decode your body to json-like struct and then just get your value from there

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type requestBody struct {
    Test       string `json:"test"`
}

func routeTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body := requestBody{}
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&body); err != nil {
        // some error handling
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    test := body.Test
    fmt.Printf(test)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have used your code(Please check the description, I have pasted it there) still it is not getting its value. Can you check this once? Thanks :)

Comment: NB: The `test` field of the `requestBody` struct should be exported

Comment: @Matteo I didn't get you. How can I export it?

Comment: @Rich to make variable exportable in golang, it should be named with uppercase letter